# How to increment a variable every n iterates according to some condition?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have the following loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Main_dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
}
```

---

Now i have one condition :

```
 if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
  }
```

---

What i wanna to do is :

if the condition is true then :

increment the variable `j` by `1` every `two iterates`,i mean like this :

**0 0 1 1 2 2**

if the condition is false then :

increment the variable `j` by `1` every `three iterates`,i mean like this :

**0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you really want:

```
int scale = dt.Rows.Count > 0 ? 2 : 3;

for (int i = 0; i < Main_dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int j = i / scale;
    ...
}
```

There may well be a better way of approaching this, but it's hard to know without more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

long version

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  if (i>0 && i%2 == 0)
     j++;
}
else
{
  if (i>0 && i%3 == 0)
     j++;
}
```

one-liner (not recommended as it takes some time to grok)

```
j += ( i>0 && i % (dt.Rows.Count > 0 ? 2 : 3) == 0) ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int j = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < Main_dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
{
      j+= i% (dt.Rows.Count>0 ? 2 : 3) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```